# Using HTTP Client to download a file from MVC causes "(System.AggregateException) One or more errors occurred"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xamarin, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have had this code in production for a very long time and this issue just started. Basically it is downloading a file from an MVC controller. These files are around 5 to 20 megabytes. And this is a PCL library running on iOS. Users are getting an error when they go to download the file from the server. I am assuming it is a timeout, but I am not 100% sure. We are unable to re-create this issue in house, but we see the errors in the logs AND users have reported this.

Anything I can do on the server side to improve this? Nothing has changed on the client, and it has become a pervasive issue for our customer base.

**Server Code**

```
    public virtual FileResult BuildDatabaseForSite(Guid organizationId, Guid siteId) {
        var basePath = RESTContext.Config.DBPath;
        var filePath = basePath + @"\" + fileId + ".db";
        byte[] existingDbBytes = null;

        using (new Impersonator(RESTContext.Config.VideoPathUsername, RESTContext.Config.VideoPathDomain,
            RESTContext.Config.VideoPathPassword)) {

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                existingDbBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        }                        
        return File(existingDbBytes, "application/octet-stream", "CompassLocal.db");
    }
```

**Client Code**

```
       public void DownloadDatabase(Guid organizationId, Guid siteId) {
            Platform.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Paths.LocalDatabase);
            var url = string.Format("organizations/{0}/Sites/{1}/InitialDatabaseCompressed", organizationId, siteId);
            var webClient = new HttpClient();
            webClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0,0,5,0);
            webClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
            var stream = webClient.GetStreamAsync(url).Result;
            using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(Paths.LocalDatabase)) {
                          stream.CopyTo(file);
            }
        }
```

**Stack Trace**

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at DataFinch.Mobile.Core.Network.RemoteAPI.DownloadDatabase (Guid organizationId, Guid siteId) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at DataFinch.Mobile.Core.Services.Registration.RegistrationService.RegisterDeviceAndDownloadDatabase (System.String username, System.String password, Guid siteId) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: What's the point of calling the async overload and blocking on the task using `Task.Result`?

Comment: This is already in a background thread, so it needs to be synchronous within that thread.

Comment: Yep, either do full async or no async otherwise you are asking for deadlocks. Besides it'd be good if you provide the actual exceptions, not just the AggregateException (i.e. iterate InnerExceptions property) as AggregateExceptions doesn't really provide much info.

Comment: FYI you can still make async/await calls and have it execute in serial.

Comment: The aggregate exception is: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The Task was canceled which I THINK is a timeout.

Comment: @Chris Usually you can see a `WebException` somewhere in the stack trace. Have you tried raising the timeout period? Has anything changed on the serverside?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously this is caused by a timeout - after all, the stack trace indicates that the exception happened in `Task.Wait(...)` - which is internally called by the Task's `Result` property further down the call stack.

Because this happens on the client side, there's nothing that you can do on the server side. You could try and make the server somehow faster. But I doubt that this would really help, because there still will be limited bandwidth available for the mobile clients - and what's more: this is depending on each single customer's data plan.

Anyway, and because you can (and you will) always have customers with very poor bandwith, the file sizes are generally way too large for targeting mobile clients. All you can do is to schedule a refactoring of the download logic for the next version of your app, splitting your downloads into much smaller chunks and and make your client code handle these kinds of problems as good as possible...

Also, blocking the entire thread, even if it is a working thread, while waiting for such a large download is a bad idea (especially on a mobile client where you have no indication of the available bandwidth). This causes the thread to be unresponsive for a very long time. You should consider changing this logic as well.